# Compile a LIST in one worksheet using data entry from another sheet on same workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

In an effort to not have the list of all persons in full view due to some wanting to keep information confidential, I wish to create a separate sheet where either using macros or formulas values entered into a row in one worksheet can be transferred to another worksheet where the list is auto compiled as shown in the sample below.

[DATA ENTRY SPREADSHEET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCfVN.png)

[COMPILED LIST SPREADSHEET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZuMk.png)

Comment: This can be achieved in both ways Formula , as well  using VBA Macro,,,!!

Comment: My gut reaction to questions requiring a separate compiled list from the data entry is you will need VBA. We do NOT provide scripting services. Although some users provide general guidance, most will only respond to specific issues you have encountered when you try to implement YOUR solution. Please edit your question, as the answer your question as stated is: "it can be done"...